# Estimate $\sup_{m>0}\mathbb P_X[X>m]\mathbb P_n[|n|<m]$ from samples of an unknown distribution $X$ given $m$ and normal distribution $n$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Suppose there are $N$ independent data points $x_i > 0$ sampled from unknown distribution $X$. Given $\sigma >0$, how to estimate the following quantity

$$\sup_{m>0}\mathbb P_X[X>m]\mathbb P_n[|n|<m], $$
where $n \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: If the $x_i$ and $n$ are independent, the most natural estimator would be
$$\sup_{m>0} \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf 1\{x_i>m\}\mathbb P_n[|n|<m]$$
And btw, an exact expression for $\mathbb P_n[|n|<m] = \mathbb P_n[|n|^2<m^2]$ [is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike how to make it computationally feasible? Since $m$ is unbounded, it might be difficult to find a suitable range and also discretization to evaluate the expression for different $m$. What I am concerned the most is what if there is a relatively sharp "jump" in $\mathbb P_X[X >m]$.

Comment: it sounds like what you're looking for is an [m-estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator), there is a vast literature on the subject. For instance you can check chapter 5 of the great book [Asymptotic Statistics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/asymptotic-statistics/A3C7DAD3F7E66A1FA60E9C8FE132EE1D) by van der Vaart. If your considerations are more practical, I think you're more likely to get appropriate help on [cross validated stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike I feel that this can be approached from theoretical pov. The practical pov is what I can currently think of. Based on your reference, I think taking derivative is the only possible approach in this case. However, the indicator function is not-differentiable. Is smoothing operation on such function possible to get the estimate of the problem that is consistent?